# Get current user's IP address in a Login Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, login, userinfo, ip

How can you get the IP address using a global variable or by querying some kind of a setup record?  I've looked at LoginHistory.obj, LoginIP, LoginGeo, but none of them show current data.  $UserInfo does not have the IP Address field either.

My goal is to compare user's current IP Address to the list of trusted IP ranges in the Login Flow.

I see how you can invoke apex from the flow, and run ApexPages.currentPage() and then get IP Address from the page headers, but I want a different solution, something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LoginFlow_IpAddress` to get the user’s current IP address and `LoginFlow_LoginIpAddress` for user’s IP address used during login, which can change after authentication. See list of [LoginFlow variables](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_login_flows.htm) available.

Check [login flow example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_examples.htm) here.